# Mac equivalent for CryptProtectData and CryptUnProtectData

Tags: macos, encryption

I need mac (carbon) equivalent for CryptProtectData and CryptUnProtectData.

Please refrain from suggesting a cocoa solution with "move to cocoa" since that's not an option.

Comment: What are `CryptProtectData` etc? Looks like something that will encrypt data with a user-specific key, so perhaps look at the Keychain for similar functionality.

Comment: Yes. These are encryption and decryption APIs on Windows.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I ended up using blowfish algorithm from Open SSL. This worked both on Windows and Mac.

Comment: …And how do you use this algorithm? Other people (like me) may have the same problem as you.

Comment: The blowfish implementation is available for use with openssl libraries. I used the same. What do you mean by "how do you use this algorithm"? If you are looking for code snippet then sorry I don't have any now. This was more than two years old. If you have specific question - will be happy to answer.

Comment: CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData are not encryption algorithms per se. The problem they are solving is secure key storage. Just using an OpenSSL symmetric cipher can hardly be considered equivalent. Other answers suggesting Keychain API are much closer to the point.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a Mac expert but I think you want to use the Keychain API on Mac. You might just use Keychain for storing/generating the protection key, and use the native encryption api's for en/de-crypting the file.

Comment: I ended up using blowfish implementation.